# Node in sitecore is auto deleted

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-workflow

I have an issue when run workflow in sitecore. When aprrove one item in master db. Then it was auto deleted from Web db.

Does is relate to access right?

Comment: Can you share some information about your server configuration or is this in your development  environment? Also what are the workflow steps how did you configure?

Comment: It is in my development environment.
I have 3 worklow : Draft, Awatting Approved, Approved.

When item in Awaiting Approved ifclick "Approve" button. It auto run command in sitecore to publish item to web DB.
After that this item is missing from web

Comment: Do you have multiple publishing targets?

Comment: Do you have any publishing restrictions set for this item?

Comment: Yes, i have 2 web db. And i dont set publishing restrictions set for this tenant

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on the Approved Button, check the workflow state of the item on the master database.

Also, check if **Next State** field on the Awaiting Approval

(Path: /sitecore/system/Workflows/[**yourWorkflowBeingUsed**]/Awaiting Approval)

It should be set to Approved. Then on the Approved (Path: /sitecore/system/Workflows/Standard Workflow/Approved), make sure the checkbox of the Final field is checked and check the **Preview publishing targets** from the Approved Item.

You need to make sure that the database from which you want to published is checked.

Thanks